# SharePoint 2013 - SuiteLinksDelegate Bar

Tags: sharepoint

I want to be able to put several links on the SuiteLinksDelegate bar at the top of my SharePoint 2013 site.  But after I deploy only the first one will show up.  Here is my elements file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Elements xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/">
     <Control Id="SuiteLinksDelegate"
         Sequence="1"
         ControlSrc="~/_ControlTemplates/15/xxxxx.SuiteBar.AllLinks/Search.ascx" />
  <Control Id="SuiteLinksDelegate"
       Sequence="2"
       ControlSrc="~/_ControlTemplates/15/xxxxx.SuiteBar.AllLinks/ITticket.ascx" />
  <Control Id="SuiteLinksDelegate"
       Sequence="3"
       ControlSrc="~/_ControlTemplates/15/xxxxx.SuiteBar.AllLinks/eLearning.ascx" />
  <Control Id="SuiteLinksDelegate"
       Sequence="4"
       ControlSrc="~/_ControlTemplates/15/xxxxx.SuiteBar.AllLinks/MBO.ascx" />
</Elements>
```

This is torturing me...

Thanks,
Moon

Here is a few of the controls ascx code:

```
Imports System
Imports System.Web.UI  
Imports System.Web.UI.WebControls
Imports System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts
Imports Microsoft.SharePoint.Portal.WebControls

Namespace ControlTemplates.xxxxx.SuiteBar.AllLinks

Partial Public Class Search
    Inherits MySuiteLinksUserControl
    ReadOnly linkText As String = "Search"
    ReadOnly linkNavigation As String = "/_layouts/15/osssearchresults.aspx"
    ReadOnly linkId As String = "SBsearch"

    Protected Sub Page_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    End Sub

    Protected Overrides Sub Render(writer As HtmlTextWriter)
        writer.RenderBeginTag(HtmlTextWriterTag.Style)
        writer.Write(".ms-core-suiteLinkList {display: inline-block;}")
        writer.RenderEndTag()
        writer.AddAttribute(HtmlTextWriterAttribute.[Class], "ms-core-suiteLinkList")
        writer.RenderBeginTag(HtmlTextWriterTag.Ul)
        RenderSuiteLink(writer, linkNavigation, linkText, linkId, False)
        writer.RenderEndTag()
        MyBase.Render(writer)
    End Sub
End Class

End Namespace
```

Another one:

```
Imports System
Imports System.Web.UI
Imports System.Web.UI.WebControls
Imports System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts
Imports Microsoft.SharePoint.Portal.WebControls

Namespace ControlTemplates.xxxxx.SuiteBar.AllLinks

Partial Public Class MBO
    Inherits MySuiteLinksUserControl
    ReadOnly linkText As String = "MBO"
    ReadOnly linkNavigation As String = "/departments/enterprise/2014MBO/default.aspx"
    ReadOnly linkId As String = "lnkMBOLink"

    Protected Sub Page_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    End Sub

    Protected Overrides Sub Render(writer As HtmlTextWriter)
        writer.RenderBeginTag(HtmlTextWriterTag.Style)
        writer.Write(".ms-core-suiteLinkList {display: inline-block;}")
        writer.RenderEndTag()
        writer.AddAttribute(HtmlTextWriterAttribute.[Class], "ms-core-suiteLinkList")
        writer.RenderBeginTag(HtmlTextWriterTag.Ul)
        RenderSuiteLink(writer, linkNavigation, linkText, linkId, False)
        writer.RenderEndTag()
        MyBase.Render(writer)
    End Sub
End Class

End Namespace
```

Comment: Elements file looks fine what about your controls (ascx files) - are tehy all set up the same way? Followed the instructions on some tutorial such as this one? http://www.learningsharepoint.com/2013/02/10/addremove-links-in-top-suitebar-skydrivesitesnewsfeed-in-sharepoint-2013/

Comment: Hi Dennis, yes they are.

Comment: Any custom style hiding the additional links (width of the suite bar fixed)?

Comment: No additional styling... I added the ascx code above.